# Переход на новый интерфейс не затрагивая старый

Tags: javascript, html

Есть сайт на котором есть некий блок с разными полями, кнопками и другими элементами интерфейса:

```
<div id="old-intrface">
 ...
</div>
```

Все это управляется библиотекой (назовем ее `BX`). Она реагирует на клики, изменения в полях, посылает ajax запросы, перерисовывает данные.

Необходимо данный интерфейс заменить на другой, но разбираться в том как оно там устроенно и работает не хочется (и нет особой необходимости).

Есть идея как это сделать, но нужна помощь в том как это лучше сделать.

Скрываем старый интерфейс и перенаправляем события из одного в другой:

```
<div id="old-intrface" style="display: none">
 ...
 <input class="old-btn-1">
 ...
</div>

<div id="new-intrface">
 ...
 <input class="new-btn-1">
 ...
</div>
```

На том же `JQuery` легко перенаправить клик по кнопке:

```
<scriptid="new-intrface">
$("new-btn-1").click(() => $("old-btn-1").click());
</script>
```

Но тут возникают проблемы:

1. Если кнопка - это ссылка, то клик по ней не имитируется (решается заменой тега `a` на тег `span`).
2. Если в старом шаблоне что-то изменилось из скрипта, то непонятно как отследить эти изменения. Например, аяксом подгрузились данные и изменился какой-то span с текстом. Вот как отследить, что он поменялся?
3. Думаю подобных проблем еще много.

Может есть библиотеки которые упростили бы данные действия? Или есть библиотеки специально для переноса интерфейса.

Слышал про `Rx`. Поможет ли он тут?

Comment: _разбираться в том как оно там устроенно и работает_ придется в любом случае, иначе нельзя будет гарантировать, что новый интерфейс показывает именно нужные данные

Comment: Готовых библиотек нету. А если изменения чисто стилистические, то может легче `css` переделать?